# Button to upload a picture is missing

Tags: support, images, user-interface

I need to upload an image to illustrate my problem. However, it is strange that some buttons are missing (see the screenshot below). How can I upload an image in this situation? Does it need a higher reputation to upload an image? Many thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I suspect you are using the mobile version of our site, so the interface is quite minimalist. Try clicking in the *full site* link that appears in the bar at the bottom of your screenshot and see if you get a proper version of TeX.sx. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Yes, all things get right now. Thank you very much! I didn't intend to use the mobile version. This problem had puzzled me since I first registered the site. And I visited the site on my computer all the time (Ubuntu 12.04, Firefox browser). Is the minimalist the defaut version?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. `:)` The full version is usually the default fallback, maybe for some reason it decided to display the mobile one instead (I once clicked the mobile option just out of curiosity and it almost drove me crazy to come back to the full site). `:)`

Comment: @soliton I changed the title of your question to hopefully reflect the problem a little bit more precisely. Hope you don’t mind. It seems like generally you know how to upload a picture.

Comment: @PauloCereda Can you make that an answer? `:)`

Comment: @doncherry: done. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Indeed you did, thanks! P.C. strikes once again `:)`. How do you get the screenshots with the phone frame?

Comment: @doncherry Thank you :).

Comment: @doncherry: there are some websites that simulate the view with smartphones. `:)` For this experiment, I used [this one](http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/). `:)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every site from the StackExchange network has a [mobile version](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/mobile-stack-exchange/). And that includes our beloved community as well. `:)`

[image: TeX on iPhone]

According to the Powers That Be:

> If we detect a whitelisted mobile device user agent, you will automatically receive an optimized mobile view of any Stack Exchange on your smartphone.

And also:

> Please note, however, that if you do find anything you can’t do on mobile, there are links at the bottom of the page to switch from mobile to desktop view at will. We also remember this setting on a per-user basis.

It's important to note that this last remark is a two-way street: that means, if by accident you choose the mobile version (link located at the bottom of the page), you will also access it and this setting will be saved, per-user basis.

[image: Link]

In other words, you'll get the mobile version

[image: Ask question]

in your desktop view:

[image: Ask question 2]

The mobile version is minimalist and has no fancy UI elements as we are used to see in our usual browsing experience.

Do not despair, we can easily go back to the full site view by clicking at the full site link located at the bottom of the page:

[image: Full site link]

And we are back in the game. `:)`

For those who read this answer until this very point, a TL;DR version of what I've written above:

[image: Bad time]

And we are done. `:)`

Comment: Did you know about this ? http://img7.joyreactor.com/pics/post/funny-pictures-auto-443177.jpeg eheh.